# Parse html code and set <span> tag

Tags: html

```
<div id=bar>
    Hey, <b>how</b> are <span><u><b>you</b>?</u></span>
</div>
```

I need to parse this code and set a span tag in a determined position identified by a start and an end.

An example is: START: 15 - END: 16

(note, "start" and "end" are set from the simple string "Hey, how are you?")

```
<div id=bar>
    Hey, <b>how</b> are <span><u><b>y<span id=someid>ou</span></b>?</u></span>
</div>
```

My idea is to parse the node "bar", getting its html code, and with a complex OOP algoritm set the span tag, but...it's hard and long to do. (everything in JS)

Is there a good programming language to semplify my work?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your asking. Although I would try javscript.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the the `HTML` tags, and then find the substring of the remaining text and surround it by a `span`, before putting back the originally extracted `HTML` tags?

Comment: @pwee167 yes thats what he is asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what you are trying to do. Try this out:

```
var text = $("#bar").text(); //jQuery gives you the text...strips the html tags
var html = $("#bar").html(); //jQuery gives you the html and text here

text = $.trim(text); //remove any whitespace from start and end

var original = text.substr(14, 2); //Get the substring you want
var updated = "<span id='someid'>" + original + "</span>"; 

html = html.replace(original, updated); //replace
$("#bar").html(html); //set new html
```

JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bbcLm97o/2/

Comment: Hey, <b>how</b> a<span id="someid">re</span> <span><u><b>you</b>?</u></span>

Comment: @user3115251 you should learn javascript/jQuery and figure out what all of this code means. Then it would be easy for you to fix the wrong position.

Comment: @user3115251 should be fixed now

Comment: wrong, because if you change the text in "Hou, how are you?" the span tag will be set in the wrong position. http://jsfiddle.net/bbcLm97o/3/

Comment: @user3115251 yes well that was not what your original question was asking.

Comment: @user3115251 if you can specify what exactly you want to do, I can probably get you a solution. And sorry I think we got on the wrong foot.